Fleet SSH Connection Issue: "Unknown SSH error" and "StreamCorruptedException"
I'm using Fleet version 1.38.89 to connect to a remote SSH development environment. While accessing the SSH environment via the terminal works fine (ssh <environment>), Fleet is unable to establish a connection. The logs show the following error:
[20240810 06:53:00.663 ERROR FR@SUPERVISOR fleet.ssh.frontend.SshSupervisor] Unknown SSH error
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Incorrect identification (line too long):  at line 8: PATH='/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bo
    at org.apache.sshd.osgi@2.12.1/org.apache.sshd.common.session.helpers.SessionHelper.doReadIdentification(SessionHelper.java:913)
    at org.apache.sshd.osgi@2.12.1/org.apache.sshd.client.session.AbstractClientSession.readIdentification(AbstractClientSession.java:525)
    at org.apache.sshd.osgi@2.12.1/org.apache.sshd.common.session.helpers.AbstractSession.messageReceived(AbstractSession.java:499)
    at org.apache.sshd.osgi@2.12.1/org.apache.sshd.common.session.helpers.AbstractSessionIoHandler.messageReceived(AbstractSessionIoHandler.java:64)
    at fleet.plugins.ssh.frontend/fleet.ssh.frontend.mina.proxycommand.ProxyCommandSession.reader(ProxyCommandSession.kt:62)
    at fleet.plugins.ssh.frontend/fleet.ssh.frontend.mina.proxycommand.ProxyCommandSession.access$reader(ProxyCommandSession.kt:25)
    at fleet.plugins.ssh.frontend/fleet.ssh.frontend.mina.proxycommand.ProxyCommandSession$reader$1.invokeSuspend(ProxyCommandSession.kt)
    at fleet.kotlin.runtime/kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at fleet.kotlin.runtime/kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
    at fleet.kotlin.runtime/kotlinx.coroutines.internal.SoftLimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(SoftLimitedDispatcher.kt:125)
    at fleet.kotlin.runtime/kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:99)
    at fleet.kotlin.runtime/kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:608)
    at fleet.kotlin.runtime/kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:873)
    at fleet.kotlin.runtime/kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:763)
    at fleet.kotlin.runtime/kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
[20240810 06:53:02.418 ERROR ??@?? f.s.f.m.p.ProxyCommandUtils] ProxyCommand '/opt/homebrew/bin/coder --global-config "/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/coderv2" ssh --stdio <environment>' killed forcefully
[20240810 06:53:03.167 ERROR ??@?? f.s.f.m.p.ProxyCommandUtils] ProxyCommand '/opt/homebrew/bin/coder --global-config "/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/coderv2" ssh --stdio <environment>' killed forcefully

It seems like Fleet might be having trouble with reading the SSH identification or with the ProxyCommand. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can suggest what might be going wrong?
Additional Info:

Fleet Version: 1.38.89
SSH connection via terminal works without issues.
The problem occurs only when trying to connect through Fleet.

What could be a possible workaround to get Fleet to connect to SSH, perhaps by adjusting the macOS SSH configuration or making other changes? If this is a bug in Fleet, it might take some time to fix, and I need a solution to continue working in the SSH environment in the meantime. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Update:
Here's the host that I use for Fleet: coder.my-workspace.main
Host coder.my-workspace.main
    HostName coder.my-workspace.main
    MaxIdentificationLength 2048
    ConnectTimeout=30
    StrictHostKeyChecking=no
    UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
    LogLevel ERROR
    ProxyCommand /opt/homebrew/bin/coder --global-config "/Users/me/Library/Application Support/coderv2" ssh --stdio my-workspace.main


I've tried to upgrade the homebrew openssh, ssh -V OpenSSH_9.7p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6 still not working.

What happens if you run the proxy command (/opt/homebrew/bin/coder --global-config "/path/to/project/config" ssh --stdio ) in your terminal? Is there any output?
In case there is output to the terminal, this is unexpected. Fleet only supports non-interactive ProxyCommand configurations.

Your issue seems to be the duplicate of: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/FL-28852/Unable-to-connect-to-remote-SSH-workspace-An-unknown-error-has-occurred. Please follow it for more details.

The output is SSH-2.0-Go @OlgaKlisho
